# Standard saving .mxd for earlier versions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, convert, arcgis-10.5

I use two computers, one with ArcGIS 10.2, the other one uses 10.5. I know, i can use "save a copy" to save he project for the older version of ArcGIS, but then, it is just a copy.

Is it possible to use a project in 10.5 and save it for the 10.2 version in a standard way?

Like just clicking on "save" and it always overwrites the 10.2 version although using 10.5?

Answer (score 1):

No, ArcGIS 10.5 will always save an MXD file as a v10.5 MXD unless you use save as option.  @BERA [This ESRI tech support article](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011219) states:

> After migrating to another version of ArcGIS, older map documents are
>   upgraded to the installed version the next time they are saved. To
>   share the map documents with older ArcGIS clients, use the Save A Copy
>   command from the ArcMap File menu to save each map document.

The article does provide a Python solution for saving to an earlier version though.

Comment: How do you know this? Is it documented somewhere?